# Cannot echo or json_decode long JSON string

Tags: php

I'm working with a large JSON data file (25 mb) in PHP.

Right now, I'm able to get the file and check it's string length, which I get 24479798 for, although I can't `echo` out the string.

After the `echo strlen()`, the rest of the script breaks down and I get no further outputs, including the `echo "Made it to the bottom";`

Why can't I get `json_decode` to work? Is this a script memory problem, a character encoding problem in the JSON data? I'm pretty stuck.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);   

if($result = file_get_contents("test.json")){
    echo "GOT IT";
}else{
    echo "NO";
}

// This works

echo "Got to here";

// This works

echo strlen($result);

// I get "24479798", which is the file string length

var_dump($diffbotResult);

// Outputs all the JSON data, so I know I have it and it's proper JSON data

$result = json_decode($result, true);

echo json_last_error_msg();

// No output

print_r($result);

// No output

echo "Made it to the bottom";

// Does not echo out anything

?>
```

Comment: verify php.ini config.

Comment: Check your error log, I suspect you're running out of memory trying to decode it and the script is crashing.

Comment: Did you check for a result of `json_last_error_msg()`?

Comment: Is error reporting configured? Should be able to get some information about what is happening

Comment: 25MB JSON screams for a database.

Comment: Yes Barmar I am trying to parse the JSON data and add it to the database, but I'm stuck being unable to decode it. Let me look into these comments and get back to you all

Comment: I added error reporting and json_last_error_msg() but there were no changes to the script's output, including no error messages

Comment: It's probably not getting that far. For a 25MB file, make sure you're running this script on the command line and not in a browser. It will take so long, the browser will timeout before you get any data. Try raising your memory limit. `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');` at the beginning of the script will probably be fine, but you can raise it higher if need be.

Comment: aynber, that fixed it. The problem was running it in the browser. This script is for a CRON job on my server, so when I ran it as a CRON job everything worked. Thank you! Please post an answer with your comment and I'll accept it so someone in the future can help find the solution

Comment: echo() does not work, what about dump()?

Comment: dump() worked. But the problem has been solved, needed to run the script on the server and not the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your trying to import a large file, the script runs longer than a browser/server will like, and will timeout before it finishes. Scripts like this need to be run on the command line or via cron to eliminate the timeout. You can also increase the memory by adding `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');` (or higher, as needed) to the beginning of the script to make sure it has enough memory to load and process the json file.